# Does the traditional Chinese way of wok break-in make wok-based dishes haram?

Tags: halal-haram, tradition

I'm not Muslim. I'm Catholic, and Chinese. Although I have many Muslim friends.

I don't know if many Muslims know this, but traditionally, when we Chinese buy a new ([cast iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cast_iron)) [wok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wok), we need to break in the wok by using a big piece of pork fat and some [garlic chives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allium_tuberosum) to vigorously scrub the cooking side of the wok until it's smooth. And then we clean the wok.

The intent is not to eat the pork fat, just to make the wok surface smooth and make frying easier. Ideally, we only need to do it once per new wok.

Does that automatically make wok-based dishes haram?

Does anybody know of alternative ways that Chinese Muslims use to break in new woks?

Comment: This is not unique to China; most cast iron cookware is seasoned using a similar method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pork in its entirety in unclean. It is not permitted to eat in a vessel which has come into contact with it, unless it is unavoidable and that too after it is washed.

> أو لحم خنزير فإنه رجس
>
> or the flesh of swine - for indeed, it is impure
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:145](http://quran.com/6/145)</sup>

> عن أبي ثعلبة الخشني أنه سأل رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال إنا نجاور أهل الكتاب وهم يطبخون في قدورهم الخنزير ويشربون في آنيتهم الخمر فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم إن وجدتم غيرها فكلوا فيها واشربوا وإن لم تجدوا غيرها فارحضوها بالماء وكلوا واشربوا
>
> Abu Tha’labah al-khushani said that he asked the Messenger of Allah(ﷺ):
>
> "We live in the neighbourhood of the People of the Book and they cook in their pots (the flesh of) swine and drink wine in their vessels."
>
> The Messenger of Allah(ﷺ) said: "If you find any other pots, then eat in them and drink. But if you do not find any others, then wash them with water and eat and drink (In them)."
>
> <sup>— [Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/28/104); also recorded by [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/72/14) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/34/12) etc.</sup>

I don't know what Chinese Muslims do, but I guess that any halal source of grease could be used instead.

Comment: Since the [seasoning process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasoning_(cookware)) polymerizes the fat, it's important to note that even after washing the seasoned coating would remain on the pan. Would the principle of istihala apply here?

Comment: @goldPseudo There is disagreement on whether *istihala* purifies a *najas al-ayn* such as pig. Also whether polymerization qualifies as *istihala* is dubious.